# When constructing a generic object, can you pass its type from a variable?

Tags: java, generics

If I have a generic class like this:

```
class SomeClass<T> { 
  public aFunction(T anArg) {
    // some implementation
  }
}
```

Is there then a way to instantiate the SomeClass, using a variable of the Class type?

I basically want to be able to do this:

```
Class var = String.class; // just an example, obviously
SomeClass<?> anInstance = new SomeClass< var >();
```

Or is there a workaround?

Comment: No. What good do you think that would do?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate indeed. Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), so at runtime generic types are not aware of their type parameters. So the simple answer is "no".

Depending on your needs, you could either use one of the `Class.newInstance` [methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html), or keep the class object in a field.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely syntactic point of view, no, you can't. Type arguments must be type names (or the wildcard, `?`) known at compile time. They cannot be variables or other expressions that evaluate to a value.

It is still unclear why you need this, especially since your `anInstance` is of type `SomeClass<?>`, in which case you wouldn't care about the type argument used.